# TortoiseGit with non-default SSH port

Tags: ssh, git

I have successfully setup gitosis on my server thanks to [this helpful howto](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way).

Versions:
Server: CentOS 5
Desktop: Windows 7
Git (on Desktop): 1.6.5.1.1367.gcd48
Client: TortoiseGit 1.3.2.0 (with msysgit 1.6.1)

**How can I clone a Git repository from my server when my SSH port is non the default (22)?**

I believe that the URL `ssh://git@MYSERVER.com:3031/gitosis-admin.git` works, but I get:

> '/gitosis-admin.git' does not appear
>   to be a git repository

Thank you.

Comment: @Chris Done. Haven't been here for a while. Also, I had only 4 questions ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
cd ~/.ssh
echo "Host MYSERVER.com" > config
echo "Port 3031" >> config
cd
git clone git@MYSERVER.com:gitosis-admin.git
```